# Styling a HTML button in CSS

Tags: html, css, typescript

I have 2 buttons in a HTML form defined as

```
<button kmdPrimaryButton size="mini" (click)="clickSection('table')">Table View</button>
<button kmdPrimaryButton size="mini"  (click)="clickSection('chart')">Chart View</button>
```

I want to add some style into the button. When i try it by adding the style attribute inside the button , I am able to do so but i want to get it done via CSS.
I created a CSS file and added the link in the component.ts file to link the HTML and CSS. But the styles that i define in the CSS is not visible in the webpage.

I tried adding

```
button {
    margin:8px;
    color:#ED7700;
}
```

and also with .button but both do not work. Is there any different way to syle the above buttons?
**Edit 1**
This is how I have linked the files in ts file

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-control-validation',
    templateUrl: './controlval.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./controlval.component.css']
  })
```

the file name is controlval.component.ts.

Comment: please add the code on how you link the html and css files together

Comment: @tommueller Added as edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add CSS file directly in your HTML file head in this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourCSSfilepath"/>
```

Try also add a class how suggested by Mamdlv and if you use external css libraries set

```
!important
```

to the styles of the button

Answer (score 0):

Just add `!important` to your css code like this:

```
button {
    margin:8px !important;
    color:#ED7700 !important;
}
```

It will replace your css button.